# How to remotely connect to HEROKU PostgreSQL database using

Tags: php, postgresql, heroku, connection, remote-access

I have a PHP application that needs to remotely connect to a HEROKU app's postgresql database and run database queries (preferably using pg_query, though PDO is ok too). I am stuck trying to 1.) obtain live db credentials using the Heroku DATABASE_URL (as they recommend), and 2) generate any kind of db connection even when hard-coded credentials are supplied. I haven't found the proper sequence of steps to make a connection. (App is running on GoDaddy hosting - mentioned for clarity.)

I am trying to connect to the database, run a select query and assign the values from the resultset to PHP variables. I can connect to the database using PGAdmin3 so remote access isn't the issue.

What I have so far (Edited- commented lines are from original post):

```
//$DATABASE_URL='$({heroku CLI string, pasted from Heroku db credentials page})';
//$db = parse_url(getenv($DATABASE_URL));

$db_url = getenv("DATABASE_URL") ?: "postgres://user:pass@host:port/dbname";
$db = pg_connect($db_url);

if($db) {echo "connected";} else {echo "not connected";}

$selectSql = "SELECT id, name FROM companies ORDER BY id";   
$result =  pg_query($db, $selectSql);

while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
    $id = $row["id"];
    $name = $row["name"];
    echo "<br>id: ".$id;
    echo "<br>name: ".$name;
}
```

What is missing to connect to the database and run queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see at least 3 problems:

1) Delete or comment out this:

```
$DATABASE_URL='$({heroku CLI string, pasted from Heroku db credentials page})';
```

2) Change this line to get the environment variable (so it looks like this). You have to set the environment variable before starting PHP. You could also hardcode the value, but not recommended:

```
$db = parse_url(getenv('DATABASE_URL'));
```

3) It doesn't look like you are actually connecting to the database, you just start your query. You have to connect first. See [heroku docs for PDO](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php#provision-a-database) or [PHP docs for pg_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-connect.php)

*Update 2018-03-23*

Here is a standalone program that will make sure it is connecting:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
$db_url = getenv("DATABASE_URL") ?: "postgres://user:pass@host:port/dbname";
echo "$db_url\n";

$db = pg_connect($db_url);
if($db) {echo "connected";} else {echo "not connected";}

$selectSql = "SELECT 1";
$result =  pg_query($db, $selectSql);

while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
    var_dump($row);
}
?>
```

Comment: This was helpful by pointing out the proper way to invoke the environment variable. Since I'm on a shared hosting platform and can't access the conf.d folder to add a DATABASE_URL environment variable, I may have to build the pg_connect connection string without that variable. Couldn't find a way to work around that so as to parse the URL and build out the connection string.

Comment: Here is the relevant environment variable I set before running the updated code: `DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:password@localhost:5432/postgres`

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `pg_connect` with the correct connection string. I don't think it's the same as the URL given via Heroku; [refer to the documentation for that one](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-connect.php).

You're also using `getenv` improperly.

```
$db_url = getenv("DATABASE_URL") ?: "some default value here";
$db = pg_connect($db_url);
```

Comment: You are right, I did need to call pg_connect properly. Also, I passed the Heroku URL into the DATABASE_URL environment variable, as in the edited code above. I couldn't get pg_connect() to recognize it as a connection string, thinking there must be another step to allow for that.